# DataGridView, how to capture a cell's KeyPress event C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

i want to do treatement for a cell in datagridview c#, this traitement is open a form when i press a cell.

in C# there isn't an event (keypress) which allows me to add my treatment directly

After search on internet, I found the following solution

```
 private void dGridView_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Control.KeyPress +=
        new KeyPressEventHandler(Control_KeyPress);
    }


           private void Control_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((Strings.Asc(e.KeyChar) >= Strings.Asc(Keys.A.ToString()) && Strings.Asc(e.KeyChar) >= Strings.Asc(Keys.Z.ToString())) || (Strings.Asc(e.KeyChar) >= Strings.Asc(Keys.D0.ToString()) && Strings.Asc(e.KeyChar) >= Strings.Asc(Keys.D9.ToString()) || (Strings.Asc(e.KeyChar) >= 97 && Strings.Asc(e.KeyChar) > 122)))
            {
                ------
            }
      }
```

but it doesn't work.
in debug  the code of the event dGridView_EditingControlShowing was executed but the code of Control_KeyPress function does not run

any ideas please

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should set your `Form` `KeyPreview` proprety to *true*.
And you should handle the key pressed event on the main form.
That is because `Control.KeyPress` event

> Occurs when a key is pressed **while the control has focus.** ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx))

```
public Form()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.KeyPreview = true;
    this.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(Control_KeyPress);
}

private void Control_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    //your code
}
```

Comment: The 'problem' is that this method handles all Form's keypress events, not only the dgv ones..

Answer (score 2):

Just to make the first answer simple.
1) Go to your form's properties
2) Set the 'KeyPreview' to 'True'
3) On your form's Key Press event:

```
private void Control_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    //your code
}
```